# ImageMagick convert thumbnail output differs based on file name

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I noticed that the binary output of `convert -thumbnail` differs based on file name (or inode or other metadata), it should be noted that visually there is no difference. Here is a bash script that copies a file and generates a thumbnail:

```
#! /bin/bash
cp avatar.png avatar2.png
convert avatar.png -thumbnail 100x100 a.png
convert avatar2.png -thumbnail 100x100 b.png
diff a.png b.png
```

It outputs:
`Binary files a.png and b.png differ`

I am surprised at this behaviour, and it raises two questions:

- out of curiosity, is there some degree of freedom in the png format? and where?
- for testing purpose, I need a stable output. Is it achievable? For example could I set a seed?

I have tried setting `-seed 123456` but the output still differ.

I am using ImageMagick version `6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101` on Ubuntu 20.04

avatar.png: [image]
avatar2.png: [image]
a.png: [image]
b.png: [image]

Comment: Post your avatar.png image. What is your Imagemagick version and platform? Are you sure the diff is not just detecting a signature difference?  What is different? Have you done a diff on avatar.png avatar2.png?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have added the additional details. avatar.png and avatar2.pg do not differ. I don't know what the diff detects, this is why I am asking the question regarding the png format.

Comment: The file size is different by 1B due to name changes, creation date differences and other slight meta data differences. I found this by looking at `identify -verbose a.png` and `identify -verbose b.png`. But the data is exactly the same via `compare -metric rmse a.png b.png null:` returns 0 (0).

Comment: Thank you this is very useful, TIL about ```identify``` and ```compare```. Indeed only metadata elements differ, now I need to find a way to strip it in order to get my stable output.

Comment: ...and convert has ```-strip``` which does the trick, with this option, the thumbnails files do not differ anymore, my issue is fixed :) If you want to put your comments into an answer I will gladly accept it, otherwise I will write a response myself.

Comment: Go ahead. You discovered -strip helps. It removes most if not all meta data, which was where the differences occurred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

As explained by fmw42, the difference is in the metadata, it can be removed by using the `-strip` option. This script shows that the output is now stable, it shows that the produced files are equal byte for byte:

```
#! /bin/bash
cp avatar.png avatar2.png
convert avatar.png -seed 123456 -thumbnail 100x100 -strip a.png
sleep 3 #delay in order to force different modify timestamp
convert avatar2.png -seed 123456 -thumbnail 100x100 -strip b.png
diff a.png b.png
```

### Additional learnings

#### identify

One can use [identify](https://imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) to explore an file's format:

```
identify -verbose a.png
```

Without strip, file creation time and original file URL were stored in the produced png. Surprisingly, when using strip, we can still see the file creation and modification time, but it is not stored in the png, it is coming from the filesystem.

#### compare

One can use [compare](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/) to compute the visual difference between two images:

```
compare -metric rmse a.png b.png diff.png
```